# Android volley - retrieve multiple rows from database

Tags: android, android-volley

Doing this in PHP was pretty easy, just using a while loop while fetching I could retrieve all the data. But how can I do that with a response on android volley? Maybe use a two-dimensional array but I'm not sure how that would work and I would retrieve the response. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Volley is supposed to call the PHP code (which should return JSON). Volley can't directly talk to a database

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, I do know that. I am using volley successfully to retrieve one row. But I don't know  how I could retrieve multiple rows.

Comment: Then that seems to be a PHP related problem, no? If volley is getting one row, PHP is only returning one row

Comment: I mean, volley is getting an array from PHP. If I return a multidimensional array from PHP, would the volley code change to handle the array?

Comment: You'd be better off returning a JSONArray containing a list of JsonObject, which correspond to each row of the database. For example http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/12/android-php-read-mysql-db-volley.html

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot! Made it work. You can post it as an answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a way
after fetching an array from php

```
$result = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
    array_push($result,array(
        'id'=>$row[0],
        'name'=>$row[1],
        'phone_number'=>$row[2]
        )
    );
    }

echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
```

This will return a jsonObject  to your android and then you can get all the rows like this

```
private void showJSON(String response){
        String name="";
        String phone_number="";
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject =new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(config.JSON_ARRAY);
            for(int x=0;x<result.length();x++) {
                JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(x);
                name = collegeData.getString(config.KEY_NAME);
                phone_number = collegeData.getString(config.KEY_PHONE_NUMBER);
                //here you can store the name and phone_number in an arraylist  
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```